# Collection Creation/Design Question

Tags: c#, collections

I need to be binding a collection to a GridView depending on the report type selected by the user.

Each report varies slightly but uses the same basic result set which has many columns. Before I bind I want to loop through the result set and copy to a simpler collection (3 string variables called 'column1', 'column2', 'column3').

Code:

```
namespace etc.etc.etc
{
    public class ReportEntity
    {
        public string column1 { get; set; }

        public string column2 { get; set; }

        public string column3 { get; set; }
    }
}

List<ReportEntity> a = new List<ReportEntity>();
ReportEntity[] b = new ReportEntity[results.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
{
    //a[i].column1 = results[i].class.desc;
    //a[i].column2 = results[i].student.firstname;
    //a[i].column3 = results[i].timescanned.ToString();

    //b[i].column1 = results[i].class.desc;
    //b[i].column2 = results[i].student.firstname;
    //b[i].column3 = results[i].timescanned.ToString();
}
```

Uncommenting where I set values for `a` gives `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`.
Uncommenting where i set values for `b` gives `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.

`results` definitely has many records. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You get `IndexOutRangeException` in the 1st case because you just created an instance of list but this list doesn't contain any elements.
- You get `NullReferenceException` in the 2nd case because you just filled array with `results.Length` of `nulls`.

What you should do is to explicitly create instance of `ReportEntity` and put in the underlying data structure.

```
List<ReportEntity> a = new List<ReportEntity>();
ReportEntity[] b = new ReportEntity[results.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
{
    a.Add(new ReportEntity() {column1 = results[i].class.desc,
                              column2 = results[i].student.firstname,
                              column3 =  results[i].student.firstname  }

    b[i] = new ReportEntity() {column1 = results[i].class.desc,
                              column2 = results[i].student.firstname,
                              column3 =  results[i].student.firstname  }
}
```

Or you can you LINQ with `Select` extenssion method to like it's mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add value to a List use the `Add` method.

Alternatively, use the select from LINQ:

```
var a = results.Select(r => new ReportEntity { 
  column1 = r.class.desc,
  column2 = r.student.firstname,
  column3 = r.timescanned.ToString()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Oh yeah. But then would I need a constructor on that entity class

Comment: The syntax above does not require any other constructor than the default